# Did Stuart Seldowitz work as Deputy Director/Senior Political Officer in the US State Department's Office of Israel and Palestinian Affairs?

Tags: united-states, israel, palestine

[According to this New York Post article, former White House official Stuart Seldowitz](https://nypost.com/2023/11/21/metro/stuart-seldowitz-harasses-halal-cart-vendor-says-killing-of-4000-palestinian-kids-wasnt-enough/) said,

> “If we killed 4,000 Palestinian kids, it wasn’t enough,” the bigot identified by internet sleuths as Seldowitz said in one of the viral clips posted to X Tuesday. “It wasn’t enough.”

The [video evidence can be found on Twitter](https://twitter.com/itslaylas/status/1726986614591885484).

[On other sources like the Democratic Underground](https://www.democraticunderground.com/?com=view_post&forum=1002&pid=18471939) they say,

> And you won't believe who he is. It's mind-blowing. Senior White House adviser Stuart Seldowitz who served as **Deputy Director/Senior Political Officer in the US State Department's Office of Israel and Palestinian Affairs** from 1999 to 2003. **He worked on the Camp David Accords.**

[Vice has also repeated this claim](https://www.vice.com/en/article/7kxmwe/stuart-seldowitz-halal-cart-harassment). Which Krystal Ball cited on breaking points [adding](https://youtu.be/XfdAXifx89g?t=210)

> He was involved in Israel and Palestinian affairs during a time when the [Oslo Accords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oslo_Accords) were still a hope of peace and peace deals were being traded back and forth?

I can't find any evidence for his credentials. Did Stuart Seldowtiz,

- Serve as Deputy Director or Senior Political Officer in the US State Department?
- Was he in the Office of Israel and Palestinian Affairs?
- Was he there as recently as 1999?
- Did he work on the Camp David Accords, the Oslo Accords, or is it likely he worked on them?

Comment: FWTW, I've seen other claims about him in terms of jobs like "Stuart Seldowitz was former Director of the National Security Council under President Obama and former diplomat for the U.S. State Department serving during five presidencies." https://www.ghlinks.com.gh/stuart-seldowitz/

Comment: @Fizz there are a lot of different variations of the claim, but I am most interested in repeating the claim that he was was in the "Office of Israel and Palestinian Affairs". It took work to source that.

Comment: **Comments about self-answering questions** have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149842/discussion-on-question-by-evan-carroll-did-stuart-seldowitz-work-as-deputy-direc);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Mostly True

The [source for that claim seems to be Gotham Government Relations](https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/gotham-government-relations-expands-teams-up-with-prestigious-law-firm-aidala-bertuna--kamins-as-lobbying-arm-301688008.html),

> Stuart Seldowitz, former **Director of the National Security Council (NSC) under President Obama and former diplomat for the U.S. State Department** serving during five presidencies, is our Foreign Affairs Chair

You can see the other elements of this claim in [*"Interview with Stuart Seldowitz on Israel-Hamas War"* by BitChute](https://www.bitchute.com/video/EH98naiWiP8D/)

> I had to choose from among all the wonderful experience you have shared with me on your resume and the most relevant of course seems that you were the **Deputy Director/Senior Political Officer in the US State Department's Office of Israel and Palestinian affairs from 1999-2003.**

Gotham Government Relations since [publicly terminated relations with him](https://twitter.com/gothamgovt/status/1727042234518995357?s=12), and they've offered to [sue Seldowitz](https://twitter.com/SchwartzDefense/status/1727148420190883907) on behalf of the street food vendor.

### On the title

Form the interview in BitChute he claims he has the title,

> Deputy Director/Senior Political Officer in the US State Department's Office of Israel and Palestinian affairs

Looking it up, this doesn't *seem* to be how the US State Department is organized. There is a [Bureau Of Near Eastern Affairs](https://www.state.gov/bureaus-offices/under-secretary-for-political-affairs/bureau-of-near-eastern-affairs/) which is led by the [Assistant Secretary of State for the Bureau of Near Eastern Affairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistant_Secretary_of_State_for_Near_Eastern_Affairs). This is not a "Director" level position though. There are [National Security Council Directors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_National_Security_Council), but they're different.

The Bureau of Near Eastern Affairs has an,

- [Office of Palestinian Affairs (OPA)](https://palestinianaffairs.state.gov/) A new office, the OPA is now led by [Handy Amr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hady_Amr) he holds the title of the first ["Special Representative for Palestinian Affairs"](https://www.state.gov/biographies/hady-amr/), but his prior title was "Deputy Assistant Secretary of State for Israeli and Palestinian Affairs"
- [Israeli Embassy](https://il.usembassy.gov/)

There is still a Deputy Assistant Secretary of State for Israeli-Palestinian Affairs, currently occupied by [Andrew P Miller](https://www.state.gov/biographies/andrew-p-miller/).

My assumption is the formal title of Seldowitz was the same as Andrew P Miller,

> "Deputy Assistant Secretary of State for Israeli-Palestinian Affairs, Bureau of Near Eastern Affairs"

But because this is 20 years later, perhaps at one point there was an official "Office of Israel and Palestinian affairs".

### Worked on the "Camp David Accords"? Almost certainly false.

I can find no information about Seldowitz and the Camp David Accords but they were signed in 1978. [The resume of Stuart M Seldowitz](https://radaris.com/Stuart-Seldowitz/1354488135) shows from 1976-1980 he was getting his Bachelor of Arts, International Affairs. He went to St John's from 1980-1981 getting his law degree. It is very unlikely a college student worked on the Camp David Accords.

The Oslo Accords were signed in 1993, and Oslo II Accords in 1995. It is at least possible that Seldowitz was involved with them, as claimed by Krystal Ball. And, as Nate Eldredge pointed out in the comments, that the author may have intended to say [2000 Camp David Summit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Camp_David_Summit) rather Camp David Accords.

From [a screenshot of this video by Lowkey](https://youtu.be/GJps2koIFNM?t=28), we can see he was did testify as the [Dayton Peace Accords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dayton_Agreement) Special Representative, but these had nothing to do with Palestine or Israel, and were related to ending the [Bosnian War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosnian_War).

[image: Seldowitz as Special Representative on the Dayton Peace Accords]

Comment: By "Camp David Accords" the author might have meant to refer to the [2000 Camp David Summit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Camp_David_Summit).

Comment: @NateEldredge that's a really good point, I'll update it.

Comment: I don't think the [National Security Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_National_Security_Council) has a position that's simply called "Director".  It does have a lot of staff positions called "Director for [particular issue]".  Maybe Seldowitz held one of those positions, but it still seems very misleading to call him "Director" which suggests a much higher level of authority.  As such, Gotham may not be a reliable source; you may want to look for official historical government sources instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge I really appreciate that level of a nuance, I'll check it out

Comment: @NateEldredge see if that update is better