# Was Stuart Seldowitz "Obama's former/ex-director of the National Security Council"?

Tags: united-states, politics

There's a [related Q](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56384/did-stuart-seldowitz-work-as-deputy-director-senior-political-officer-in-the-us) here about some other past job claims about him, but there's also, e.g. in [the Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-12777305/Obama-advisor-Islamophobic-tirade-Hamas-Israel.html):

> Barack Obama's former director of the National Security Council has been unmasked as a man seen unleashing an Islamophobic attack on a street vendor.

It's then partially repeated that

> Seldowitz [...] worked in the Obama administration.

Or https://www.ghlinks.com.gh/stuart-seldowitz/

> Stuart Seldowitz was former Director of the National Security Council under President Obama and former diplomat for the U.S. State Department serving during five presidencies.

The latter seems to suggest he was [also] a career diplomat which appears more likely given his [own auto-biography](https://web.archive.org/web/20190122041000/http://gothamwashington.com/stuart-seldowitz-foreign-affairs-chair/), in which e.g. says he won State Department’s Superior Honor Award three times.

**What job did he have in the Obama administration though?** That's not at all clear from his own brief auto-bio (linked above), which doesn't seem to verify anything related to the [National Security Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_National_Security_Council), which is distinct from the State Department.

Comment: This is almost the very same question I asked.. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/56385/3835

Comment: @EvanCarroll: no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Whitehouse.gov press release](https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/the-press-office/expected-attendees-tonights-state-dinner) from 2009 lists "Mr. Stuart Seldowitz, Acting Director for South Asia, NSC".

A [Foreign Policy](https://foreignpolicy.com/2010/08/27/nsc-gets-a-new-south-asia-director-filling-out-administrations-india-team/) article from 2010 clarifies the structure a little:

> [Michael] Newbill will join a team that includes Stuart Seldowitz, the other South Asia director under [Anish] Goel, whose portfolio doesn’t include Pakistan or Afghanistan.

If [his private LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/stuart-m-seldowitz-00116636) is to be trusted, it was a short appointment: "National Security Council South Asia Directorate. Feb 2009 - Jan 2011 2 years."

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/what-is-the-meaning-of-acting-for-position-like-south-asia-director-in-the-nsc

Comment: He says the same thing in a BitChute interview https://www.bitchute.com/video/EH98naiWiP8D/ around 2 mins in, that he was 2 years in the NSC, but not worked on the Middle East there, but on AfPak.

Comment: Oddly enough that seems contradicts what FP wrote in that quote, regarding his area in the NSC. But that sentence is a bit ambigous, and the one non working on AfPak was Goel, based on the previous sentences: "Over at the NSC, the Pakistan shop is run by a Bush holdover, retired Lt. Gen. Doug Lute. He reports up to Dennis Ross, who oversees an enormous swath of the map termed the “Central Region.” Goel, the NSC South Asia director, does not handle Pakistan but also reports up to Ross, we’re told."